# Смена картинки через админ панель WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Как реализовать смену картинки через админ панель в WordPress, чтобы в будущем клиент сам мог менять картинки? Не могу найти решения такого вопроса, может есть какой-то плагин?

Comment: [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), [Carbon Fields](https://carbonfields.net/), [Toolset](https://toolset.com/), [Meta Box](https://metabox.io/) и прочие аналоги.

Comment: Ну и не за чем дублировать [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1404510/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-wordpress)

Comment: Где "менять"? В большинстве случаев это есть из коробки.

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется в виду смена аватара пользователя, то, вероятно, поможет вот это: WP User Avatar (плагин)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но нет, получается у меня в верстке которую "натянул" есть картинки, которые клиент желает изменить в будущем, с тем как реализовать смену текста разобрался, а изображенией - нет(